# Component of vector in theperpendicular dirction of given vector

Tags: vectors

> [image]

In this i could not get any start , I am very confused .

In solving this type of problems .

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225494/component-of-a-vector-perpendicular-to-another-vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We perform a decomposition
$$
p = p_\parallel + p_\perp
$$
where $p_\parallel$ is parallel to $q$ and $p_\perp$ is perpendicular to $q$.

Then
$$
p \cdot q 
= (p_\parallel + p_\perp) \cdot q
= p_\parallel \cdot q + \underbrace{p_\perp \cdot q}_0
= p_\parallel \cdot q 
$$
and
$$
p \cdot q
= p_\parallel \cdot q
= \lVert p_\parallel \rVert \lVert q \rVert s
$$
with $s = \cos \angle(p_\parallel,q) \in \{-1, 1\}$ so we have
$$
\lVert p_\parallel \rVert s 
= \frac{p \cdot q}{\lVert q \rVert}
$$
This gives
$$
p_\parallel 
= \lVert p_\parallel \rVert s \frac{q}{\lVert q \rVert}
= \frac{p \cdot q}{\lVert q \rVert} \frac{q}{\lVert q \rVert}
= \frac{p \cdot q}{q^2} q
$$
and finally
$$
p_\perp 
= p - p_\parallel 
= p - \frac{p \cdot q}{q^2} q
$$

Here is a rendering of the scene:

[image: the scene]

The vector above the plane $z=0$ is $q$, the long vector below the plane is $p$. We see the decomposition into $p_\parallel$ (green arrows) and $p_\perp$ (red arrows). We notice that $p_\parallel$ points into the opposite direction of $q$, thus we have $s = -1$.

Calculation gives
$$
p_\perp = (11/3, 7/3, -4/3)^\top
$$

Comment: $p_\parallel 
= \lVert p_\parallel \rVert s \frac{q}{\lVert q \rVert}$ , how you write this equation

Comment: It is just splitting a vector $u$ into its length $\lVert u\rVert$ and its direction vector $d_u = u / \lVert u \rVert$: $u=\lVert u\rVert d_u$.  Now the vector $p_\parallel$ is parallel to $q$. So we either have $d_p = d_q$ or $d_p = - d_q$, which I wrote as $d_p = s d_q$ with $s = \pm 1$.

Comment: Great explanation

Answer (score 1):

Find out the projection of $\bf p$ onto $\bf q$ and then subtract that from $\bf p$ to get the component perpendicular to $\bf q$. You will get the following expression $\textbf{a}=\textbf{p}-\frac{<\textbf{p,q}>}{||\textbf{q}||^2}\textbf{q}$

Comment: Why we are subtracting

Comment: Note that this, $\frac{<\textbf{p,q}>}{||\textbf{q}||^2}\textbf{q}$, is the component of $\textbf{p}$ in direction of $\textbf{q}$. Now subtracting the portion of $\textbf{p}$ in the direction of  $\textbf{q}$ from $\textbf{p}$ will give us the part of $\textbf{p}$ perpendicular to $\textbf{q}$. To verify that take dot product of $\textbf{a}$ with $\textbf{q}$ and use the fact that $<q,q>=||q||^2$